# MongoDB Array of ID's to compare and pull a value

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm a little newer to using MongoDB and NoSQL for my stack. ULTIMATELY, I'm switching to NoSQL for the fact of JSON parsed data already. I can accomplish what I want in MySQL - but I'm also attempting to teach myself something new.

Currently, I have no problem getting connected and setting up my Schemas for NodeJS. I have a document within MongoDB that returns what my customers pay on fuel according to National Averages - our customers give us ranges for us to be able to find what specific dollar amount they are paying.

My MongoDB Document looks as the following :

```
main_database
|- customerFSC (name of document)
|-- 
{
"_id":{"$oid":"5e5ecc04e8da861114079ab2"},
"custID":"01",
"custName":"Customer ABC",
"avgLow":["1.19","1.24","1.29","1.34","1.39","1.44","1.49","1.54","1.59","1.64","1.69","1.74","1.79","1.84","1.89","1.94","1.99"],
"avgHigh":["1.239","1.289","1.339","1.389","1.439","1.489","1.539","1.589","1.639","1.689","1.739","1.789","1.839","1.889","1.939","1.989","2.039"],
"custFscPM":["0.01","0.02","0.03","0.04","0.05","0.06","0.07","0.08","0.09","0.10","0.11","0.12","0.13","0.14","0.15","0.16","0.17"]
}
```

If fuel average for the week is at 1.215 - it would be ranged between the avgLow of 1.19 and the avgHigh of 1.239 but return the actual pay of 0.01 in custFscPM

My MongoDB Mongoose Node code is as follows

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const fscCustSchema = new Schema({
    custID: String,
    custName: String,
    avgLow: Array,
    avgHigh: Array,
    custFscPM: Array
  },
  { collection: 'customerFSC' }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model('customerFSC', fscCustSchema);




    fscCustModel.find( { $and: [ 
      { $gte: [ { avgLow: USAFscAVG } ] },
      { $lte: [ { avgHigh: USAFscAVG } ] }
    ]},function(err2,resp2) {
      if (err2) console.log("Error Thrown Looking up Fuel:" + err2);
      console.log(resp);
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) which is way to powerful way of querying MongoDB than using `.find()`, Try below query :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
      $project: {
        custFscPM: {
          $arrayElemAt: [
            "$custFscPM",
            {
              $indexOfArray: [
                "$avgLow",
                {
                  $arrayElemAt: [
                    {
                      $filter: {
                        input: "$avgLow",
                        cond: {
                          $gte: [
                            {
                              $toDouble: "$$this"
                            },
                            1.94 // Your input
                          ]
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    0
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ])
```

Looking at your data, in this query we're finding the element in **avgLow** array which is greater than or equal to passed in value & getting it's index & find the element from **custFscPM** at the same index would resolve your requirement.

**Note :** As your values in **avgLow** are strings we need to convert those to double in order to do comparison.

**Test :** [MongoDB-Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/FcAtnIXtqCG)

Comment: You my friend are a saint, as this does pull it from the document. Thank you. When I pass my input/value (1.94) does this need to be passed as a string or as numeric?

Comment: @elisciandrello : Pass it as numeric (double), that way it's guaranteed that comparison is apt !! As comparison on two numeric values of type string is not feasible..

Comment: Figured that out by just passing the pulled string to a var and processing it through Number() --- thank you for the assistance!